# Automatically reject conflicting Google Calendar invites

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business

How do I auto-decline invites that are overlapping with the events I have already accepted invite for?

Apparently, Google stopped supporting [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/13045640?hl=en) feature and the Labs features is not even visible to me as mentioned on [this page](https://sites.google.com/a/gooapps.edu.vn/app-learning-center/tips-library/gmail/automatically-decline-events-if-you-have-a-scheduling-conflict)

I am okay with having to write any Google AppScript code as well.